Is the covariant structure of a covector with respect to coordinate changes forced, or is it a consequence of its definition as a linear functional?
In "The Geometry of Physics, an Introduction" (Theodore Frankel), we get the usual definition of a covector. Nominally, on page xxxii we get that

From Frankel:
$du^i$ is the linear functional the reads off the $i$th component of any vector $\mathbf v$ with respect to the basis vector of the coordinate system $u$". Then he writes our real linear functional $V \xrightarrow{\quad \alpha \quad } \mathbb R$,
$$ \alpha = \sum_i \alpha_i (u) \; du^i = (a_1 , \dots , a_n) (du^1 , \dots , du^n)^\intercal = a \; du$$

This is the usual sort of definition that you would find for a covector. Casually speaking, $\alpha$ behaves a bit like one of the "sideways" vectors that we would see in linear algebra, which would would induce a dot (inner product) with our "vertical" vector $\mathbf v$. On the next page xxxiii , Frankel gives another feature of the covector that I've seen mentioned on a few Wikipedia articles, but I haven't seen explained:

From Frankel (again):
Under a change of coordinates, using the chain rule, $\alpha = a ' \, du' = a \, du = a {du \over du'} du'$, and so
$$ \alpha' = a {d u \over du'} = a { 1 \over \left( {d u' \over du}\right) } \quad \text{i.e.,} \quad a'_j = \sum_i a_i {du^i \over du'^j} $$
Not that by definition, if $\alpha$ is a covector and $\mathbf v$ is a vector, then the value
$$\alpha (\mathbf v) = a v = \sum_i a_i v^i \quad \quad \quad \quad (1) $$
is invariant, i.e., independent of the coordinates used.

I'm primarily concerned with the property that
$$ \alpha = a ' \, du' = a \, du \quad \quad \quad \quad (2)$$
Is this an actual property of covectors that is always true as a consequence of property (1), or is it introduced as an axiom of sorts in (2)? Frankel's usage of chain suggests that he derives things off of (2), rather than deriving (2) from chain rule, but I could be mistaken.
Is "contravariant" and "covariant" here related directly to the usage of terms in category theory? If I take the categorical structure of an ordinary vector in our coordinate system, and I reverse the arrows (as you do with covariant and contravariant categories), will it always generate the linear function (covector) which will (inevitably?) in opposite proportion to my coordinate changes? If so, I would like to see either a derivation or source for derivation that gives us (2) from (1). A categorical example would also be appreciated.
Instead, did the physicists and perhaps some mathematicians introduce (2) as an axiom that they wanted to give certain invariants in their system? If so, when do non physics inclined mathematicians also adopt this axiom? Are there cases where you wouldn't want to adopt it?
Thanks in advance!

Many questions and, omg, category theory of which I have no clue. In short: (2) says that  one and the same one form $\alpha$ can be expressed in different coordinates. It is the pedestrian chain rule that lurks behind coordinate transformations, pullbacks, pushforwards and what  not. Does it matter what the axioms are as long as everything is consistent?

There are many books on differential forms written by mathematicians which explain what is really going on. Consider reading one of these.

It is indeed a consequence of being a linear functional. And it's really just linear algebra.

@MoisheKohan Can you give a book, chapter from a book, page or reference that describes this behavior then?

For instance, L.Tu "Introduction to manifolds". He does a very thorough job with forms (including covectors): first multilinear algebra 1.3, then forms on $R^n$, 1.4, then on manifolds, 5.17, 5.18. He is too slow for my taste, but for a novice, such careful treatment is very useful.
